# Jetty not displaying jsp page anymore

Tags: jsp, jetty

My jetty is not displaying jsp anymore. It was working well a while ago. Has this happened to anyone? Do you know the cause for this kind of error to occur.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in Jetty's logs? If so post them up here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I upgraded to jetty 8.1 and it runs so much better. Just that 8.1 seems to load up slower than 7xx. Still no clue why jsp display problem happened.